# How to run a Jenkins job every X minutes between the hours of Y and K?

Tags: linux, jenkins

For instance, I would like to run a Jenkins build every 10 minutes between 1AM and midnight. I thought maybe

H/10 H(1-23) * * *

would work, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the build to run every 10 minutes between precisely 1AM and midnight, you should use

```
*/10 (1-23) * * *
```

The H randomizes the entry, so the minute value in your schedule could be anything from 0 to 9, 10 to 19, etc.  I don't think the H has any effect on a range value such as (1-23).

Comment: thank you - that works although it seems like Jenkins does not like the () around 1-23.